# Scale an array of values with lightning speed

Tags: c++

I have an array of double with 12,000 entries.  I need to scale each entry's value by a factor (e.g. 0.3345, or 6.78. whatever).

What I did was to loop each entry and perform the multiplication.  As I am working on an PPC-based 100MHz embedded system, the large number of multiplication calls is slowing it down tremendously.

I there a way to do this faster.  An analogy would be like initializing a block of memory -- one would use memset which is very fast.  I wonder if there is an equivalent method.

Comment: If you need to multiply the values, then you need to multiply the values...

Comment: if your compiles doesn't do loop unrolling, maybe you can write a small wrapper for the task.

Answer (score 12):

I'd like to answer with a question: Do you really *need* to actually multiply each value?

Personally I would consider using a better data structure which hides the actual content of the array in a private variable and provides a scale-function which just updates a `scale`-field. The public access methods of the data structure can then simply scale the values according to the scale-field on a per-need basis.

Comment: Scaling is one example. The general problem was "multiplication in a large for-loop". Another instance of this problem was when I tried to do modulation of 2 very large arrays, but not large enough that doing it in frequency domain (FFT) will speed it up. Indeed, I solved that with another method altogether (long story), but not every situation will have another method, plus we are always short on time. So, I was wondering if there is such a technique to speed up multiplication in a for-loop.

Comment: I doubt it. Personally I would (as a last resort) carefully examine the assembly instructions emitted by the compiler. A simple task like this can probably be optimized quite a bit, and if the compiler hasn't done a good job at it, it should probably be evident how to improve it.

Comment: Yeah, it's in voltage.  But i'll take all the suggestions given in mind while trying to solve this

Answer (score 2):

There is a reason why `memset` can be very fast: there is no dependency on the previous value of the memory. This is not your case.

There are a few solutions for your problem. The first is to change the algorithm so you can prevent the multiplication in the first case. This is what I would be shooting for. An example is wrapping the array that multiplies an element when it is accessed.

If the multiplication in the data can not be avoided your best bet is to parallelize the multiplication, dividing the array in `n` parts (where `n` is equal to the amount of processors), where each part gets assigned to a thread for the multiplication. This is an example:

```
void multiply_block(double *array, const double val, const size_t len) {
    int n = (len + 7) / 8;

    /* duff's device */
    switch (len % 8) {
        case 0:      do {    *array++ *= val;
        case 7:              *array++ *= val;
        case 6:              *array++ *= val;
        case 5:              *array++ *= val;
        case 4:              *array++ *= val;
        case 3:              *array++ *= val;
        case 2:              *array++ *= val;
        case 1:              *array++ *= val;
                     } while(--n > 0);
    }
}

void multiply_block_parallel(double *array, const double val, const size_t len) {
    const int threads = get_num_processors();
    int i = 0;

    /* start all but the last thread */
    while (i < (threads - 1)) {
        start_thread(multiply_block,
                     array + i * (len / threads), val,  len / threads);
        i++;
    }

    /* start last thread with remaining data */
    start_thread(multiply_block,
                 array + i * (len / threads), val, len - i * (len / threads));
}
```

In this example `get_num_processors` returns the amount of processors, and `start_thread(func, args...)` is a function that starts a new thread executing `func` with the arguments given. You should obviously replace those functions with real-life equivalents.

Comment: with a single core threads will just slow down the process. also, if multiplication is fast on the CPU then this process is memory bounded, so it won't help either (unless the data is already in cache)

Comment: Would it help to parallelize if there are not multiple cores? It's not stated explicitly, but I get the impression this is a single-processor platform.

Comment: Added that `n` should be equal to the amount of processors.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, looking for other algo is the best best, but like I mentioned in another comment below, it is time consuming to think of other solutions, so I was hoping there is a solution for a "many multiplications in a for-loop" ... but I guess there aren't any.   And thanks for the parallelism idea -- never thought of that, I will research a bit on this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would suggest you to consider to go for fixed points if you can, it would greatly improve performance simplifying the task to integer multiplication.

In this case you could pre-calculate a "multiplication table". Thus, say you want to multiply a lot of x<256 numbers by 3, you would generate:

```
  1 * 3 = 3
  2 * 5 = 6
  4 * 3 = 12
  8 * 3 = 24
 16 * 3 = 48
...
128 * 3 = 384
```

It's even very fast as you just have to shift the results to left by one. Then for each element you have to multiply you take the last bit, add the corresponding number to the result from the table and shift the value to right. This way you simplify multiplication to 8 additions.